# Keyword search with special characters

Tags: apex

How can we do a keyword search with special characters in a string with pattern and matcher class
I used similar code as below to do the same. However this does not work if there are special characters like ( , ), - present in the keyword. I tried using \w to the code but it did not work.

```
static Boolean keywordSearch(String input, String keywordPhrase)
{
    return Pattern.compile('(?i)\\b\\w' + keywordPhrase + '\\b\\w').matcher(input).find();

}

String corpus = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy (dog)';
system.assert(keywordSearch(corpus, 'lazy (dog)')); //Fails and it is not detected
system.assert(keywordSearch(corpus, 'QUICK')); // Pass
system.assert(!keywordSearch(corpus, 'jump')); //Pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that if your keyword ends with a non-word character, wrapping it in word boundary tokens will fail to match. If you want to still find exact matches, you may wish to conditionally add the `\b` tokens based on if the keword phrase starts or ends with word boundaries. You probably also want to escape non-word, non-space characters.

```
Pattern startsWordBoundary = Pattern.compile('^\\b'); // ^ matches start of string
Pattern endsWordBoundary = Pattern.compile('\\b$');   // $ matches end of string

static Boolean keywordSearch(String input, String keywordPhrase)
{
    String expression = '(?i)';

    if (startsWordBoundary.matcher(keywordPhrase).find()) expression += '\\b';
    expression += escapeExpression(keywordPhrase);
    if (endsWordBoundary.matcher(keywordPhrase).find()) expression += '\\b';

    return Pattern.compile(expression).matcher(input).find();
}
static String escapeExpression(String phrase)
{
    return phrase.replaceAll('([^\\w\\s])', '\\\\$0');
}

String corpus = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy (dog)';
system.assert(keywordSearch(corpus, 'lazy (dog)'));
system.assert(keywordSearch(corpus, 'QUICK'));
system.assert(!keywordSearch(corpus, 'jump'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian. Let me try this out. It will be great if you could direct me to any link where i can dive deep to understand the \\b, \\w, ?i tags. I could not find it as far as i googled. Thanks again for helping..

Comment: Hi @adrian.. this worked. Thanks for helping! It will be great if you coul d point me to any link where i can find details about these tags

Comment: I juse https://regex101.com/